# Where does this multithreaded app appear in Windows TaskManager?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio

This program spawns a thread and the two threads communicate.It works fine and I would like to see how it appears in Windows Task Manager so I can understand it better. When I look in Task Manager I see this:
[image]

Should there be two entries somewhere in Task Manager because there are two threads? Is it all happening in .Net so there's nothing else to see in Task Manager?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
namespace SensorNamespace {
    class Sensor {
        private ISensorInterface sensorInterface;
       
        public Sensor(ISensorInterface sensorInterface) {
            this.sensorInterface = sensorInterface;
        }

        private void ThreadStart() {
            while (true) {
                // The sensor reads a value from the real world and converts it to a double. 
                // We would need the unit of measure from the sensor manufacturer.
                float value = (float)(new Random()).NextDouble();
                sensorInterface.Update(value);
                Thread.Sleep(500);  // A nice pause because analog sensors are slow.
            }
        }
        public void Start() {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ThreadStart));
            thread.Start();
        }
    }
}


using System;
using SensorNamespace;
using System.Threading;

namespace MultithreadedSensorInterfaceCSharp {
    class Demo : SensorNamespace.ISensorInterface {
        private static float sensorValue;
        private static Sensor temperatureSensor;
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Demo demo = new MultithreadedSensorInterfaceCSharp.Demo();
            SensorNamespace.Sensor sensor = new SensorNamespace.Sensor(demo);
            temperatureSensor = new SensorNamespace.Sensor(demo);
            temperatureSensor.Start();
            while (true) {
                Console.WriteLine(sensorValue);
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        }

        void ISensorInterface.Update(float value) {
            sensorValue = value;
        }
    }
}

namespace SensorNamespace {
    interface ISensorInterface {
        void Update(float value);
    }
}
```

The entire project is here: https://github.com/nicomp42/MultithreadedSensorInterfaceCSharp

Comment: TaskManager shows **processes**, not threads. You could use something like [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to view the threads.

Comment: Or [Process explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)